# Issue with double permission request using permission_handler in Flutter"

Tags: flutter, permissions

First of all, I am not familiar with English, so please understand that I am asking a question through translation.

I'm building an app using flutter that uses photos and phone permissions. When the user starts the app, we wanted to check whether the app's permissions were granted and decide whether to run the app. So, I used the [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) library in flutter and wrote it as follows.

```
// Check the required permissions to use the app
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

import '../messagebox/bloc/message_box_state.dart';
import '../messagebox/page/message_box_page.dart';

/// It sequentially asks for the necessary permissions: phone and camera.
Future<String> callPermissions() async {
  PermissionStatus phoneStatus = await Permission.phone.request();
  if (!phoneStatus.isGranted) {
    return 'failed';
  }
  else { //phoneStatus.isGranted == true
    PermissionStatus cameraStatus = await Permission.camera.request();
    if (!cameraStatus.isGranted) {
      return 'failed';
    }
    else {
      return 'success';
    }
  }
}

/// Check permissions and, if you do not have the permissions, perform permission derivation, such as providing a /// page to set permissions.
void checkPermission(BuildContext context) async {
  if (await callPermissions() == "success") {
    //If allowed
  }
  else { // If not allowed
    bool? permissionResult =
    await MessageBoxPage.popUpMessageBox(
        context,
        'Camera permission and phone permission must be allowed to use the app. Would you like to go to the settings page to allow?',
        MessageBoxType.ReplyTwoMessageBox);
    if (permissionResult == true) {
      bool? permissionResult2 =
      await MessageBoxPage.popUpMessageBox(
          context,
          'When you press OK, the app will automatically close to go to the settings page. Please run it again after setting.',
          MessageBoxType.ReplyOneMessageBox);
      if (permissionResult2 == true) {
        // When you press Yes, you will be moved to settings.
        openAppSettings();
        SystemNavigator.pop();
      }
    } else {
      bool? permissionResult2 =
      await MessageBoxPage.popUpMessageBox(
          context,
          'The app cannot proceed because the required permissions to use the app are not granted. The app quits.',
          MessageBoxType.ReplyOneMessageBox);
      if (permissionResult2 == true) { // 예를 눌렀을 때 설정으로 이동한다.
        SystemNavigator.pop();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When using another app, permission is asked once the first time, and the next time it is not asked for permission, so I have to access it directly from the app's settings, but now it asks 'twice'. Why am I asked ‘twice’ instead of once? That's my question.

I created it with version 10.4.3 of permission_handler, and tested it on Android 12 with a cell phone model SM-N971. Surprisingly, this problem was resolved at some point, but the problem is occurring again. I've tried to solve the problem somehow, but I think I need more advice. I would appreciate your reply.

```
PermissionStatus phoneStatus = await Permission.phone.request()
```

I also tested by changing the content of the above text and changing the timing of the questions. The problem continued to unfold.

I also tried changing the library version from 10.4.3 to 10.4.1. But the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sequentially requesting permissions, consider batching them. By grouping permission requests, you can potentially prompt users in a single dialog, which enhances the user experience:

```dart
Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
  Permission.camera,
  Permission.phone
].request();
```

Check Permission Status Before Requesting:
Before directly requesting permissions, first verify their current status. This can help you avoid unnecessary prompts and improve the user experience:

```dart
if (await Permission.phone.isGranted) {
  // Permission was previously granted.
} else if (await Permission.phone.isDenied) {
  // Permission was previously denied. You can request it again.
}
```

By incorporating these strategies, you can make the permission request flow smoother and more intuitive for your app's users.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Currently the same situation is happening. However, I think this problem is also a problem with my device, so I'd like to try something else first. Still, I think I could have made some improvements using your code. Thank you again for your reply. :)